# jquery and user city

Tags: jquery

at first, sorry about my english. 
My question is: I have php generated dynamic div, with id and image source.. If user click on dynamic div its swap img source. 
My script works, but its swaps all div images, but not selected div img source.
Where is problem? how I can swap clicked div img source? Can someone, help me please?

My script:

```
<script> ( function($) { 
  $(document).ready( function() { 
    $("div.area_map").click( function () { 
      $('div[id^=grass]').each(function(div) { 
        $('img.hoverswap').css("width","229"); 
        $('img.hoverswap').css("height","124");
        $('img.hoverswap').attr("src","default/citymap/D5.png"); 
        $('img.hoverswap').css("z-index", "9999") 
       } ); 
     }); 
   } ) ( jQuery ); 
</script>
```

And div:

```
<div class="area_map" id="grass
  <?php echo $k+$st_x/2; ?>" 
  style='cursor:pointer; width:118px; height:51px; position:absolute; 
  left:<?php echo $st_x; ?>px; 
  top:<?php echo $st_y; ?>px;'>
  <img src="default/citymap/Zale2.png" name="table" border="0" 
    usemap="#tableMap" class="hoverswap" 
    style='cursor:pointer; z-index:-300; width:118px; height:51px;'/> 
</div>
```

Comment: And div: <div class="area_map"  id="grass<?php echo $k+$st_x/2; ?>" style='cursor:pointer; width:118px; height:51px;  position:absolute; left:<?php echo $st_x; ?>px; top:<?php echo $st_y; ?>px;'><img src="default/citymap/Zale2.png" name="table" border="0" usemap="#tableMap" class="hoverswap" style='cursor:pointer; z-index:-300; width:118px; height:51px;'/>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use**

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $("div.area_map").click( function () { 
                $('img.hoverswap')
                .css(
                {
                "width":"229",
                "height":"124",
                "position":"absolute",//to make z-index work
                "z-index", "9999"
                })
                .attr("src","default/citymap/D5.png");
       }); 
   });
```

also edit css for  **div.area_map**

```
div.area_map{
 position:relative;
}
```

this will make your z-index work relative to area_map

Comment: Can you give me your email? I want to send full source code to You.

Comment: I cant put php, just html, java and css

Comment: you just add , every one including me can see and change if needed. or you can put your email in jsfiddle so every one can contact.

Comment: I have another question: when user selected dinamic tab its swaped image. How to save user made changes in SQL or maybe in xml file :)

Comment: if its working voteup and accept as solution. Post a new question as new post; but simple answer will be $.post('sendData.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});

Comment: ya you cant vote coz u dont have point, but you can accept as solution. just click right sign. you will get point after that, after that in future you will be able to vote as well.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the answers given by JapanPro and zrytane, `$('img.hoverswap')` finds all matches in the document, regardless of what scope you call it from.

`$('img.hoverswap', this)` restricts the scope to `this` rather than the default of `document`.

`$(this).find('img.hoverswap')` sets up a jQuery wrapper for `this` and then searches within it.

Both work equally well but you'd have to benchmark them yourself to see if there's a speed difference. (Intuitively, there shouldn't be)

However, your script is inefficient since you're repeatedly creating and discarding jQuery objects. Here's how I'd code it:

```
<script>
 (function($) { 
  $(document).ready( function() { 
    $("div.area_map").click( function () { 
        $('img.hoverswap', this).css({
            width: "229",
            height: "124",
            zIndex: "9999"
        }).attr("src","default/citymap/D5.png"); 
    }); 
  }); 
 }) ( jQuery ); 
</script>
```

That way, you're only creating the wrapper for the img.hoverswap query once and then sending multiple commands. You'll also notice I've used the map form of .css() which, due to restrictions on the Javascript object literal, uses camelCase rather than dashed-names.

Comment: Tnx, its worked. But there is problem with z-index. Swaped D5.png is under grass.png?

Comment: Pull it up in a DOM Inspector (Chrome built-in or Firefox extension) and take a look at the z-index values in the "computed style" listings for both images. That'll tell you where the problem is.

Comment: I have another question: when user selected dinamic tab its swaped image. How to save user made changes in SQL or maybe in xml file :)

Comment: Generally, you're supposed to only ask one question per StackOverflow entry. This is a Q&A system, not a discussion forum. However, if you open a new question and link me to it, I'll see if I can help you. (Just make sure you don't forget to mark one of our answer to this one as "Best Answer" eventually)